# Maintain div scroll position after rotation

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a `div` full of thumbnails that I've set to rotate based on mobile device orientation with CSS.

The problem is, when rotating the device, the `div` gets redrawn and the current position of the `scroll bar` is set back to the beginning of the list.

I've tried a few different ways to maintain the position of the list. I've had *some* luck with the following `jQuery` code snippet:

```
// record location of scroll for orientation
// change handling:
$('#mapLeft').on('scroll', function() {
    offset.scrollTop = $('#mapLeft').scrollTop();
    offset.scrollLeft = $('#mapLeft').scrollLeft();
});

// detect orientation change and make sure list
// stays in proper location:
$(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
    alert('from orientationchange event');
    $('#mapLeft').scrollTop(offset.scrollLeft);
    $('#mapLeft').scrollLeft(offset.scrollTop);
});
```

The problem is, if I remove the `alert`, it doesn't work, but I can't figure out why.

#### 1. Is anyone able to shed light on why the alert seems to be necessary to get handler to actually scroll back to the previously set positions?

#### 2. Is there a way I can accomplish this without needing the silly alert?

I would have thought this would be a common issue, but I haven't found a solution that works for me. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Here's the CSS:

```
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
    #mapLeft {
        float: left;
        height: 90%;
        margin-left: 1%;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 140px;
    }
}

@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
    #mapLeft {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        height: 140px;
        width: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

Jade HTML template:

```
html
  head
    title #{title}
    meta(name="viewport", content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0")
  body
    .border
    #mapLeft
    #mapRight
    #mapCanvas
    .border
```

I would have thought this would be a common issue, but I haven't found a solution that works for me. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: where is your html code ?

Comment: a silly advice, see if it works and only try if you can't find any other option. give a blank setTimeout of 500 milliseconds. It will be unnoticeable and may work :-) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: @AtanuCSE Unfortunately I haven't gotten it to work with a setTimeout no matter how long I set the timeout for -- even ridiculous totals like 5000 ms. I  don't understand what the alert is doing that's so special ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a set timeout or preferable try run the scroll function after the redraw change... like a callback or something :)

I think it can be that you in the css have a transition at maybe 0.3s .. so you would need the timeout then to 300ms. Play around with it :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in the first part of your answer, but I've definitely tried wrapping the calls to .scrollTop and .scrollLeft in a setTimeout() -- unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work no matter how long I set the timeout for.

Comment: maybe there is a orientationchange complete function you can call. But still it's weird a timeout doesnt fix it. However, the alert I think pauses it, so the scroll function doesnt run and keeps the old values. Maybe you need to set the offsets manually in the orientationchange function, not rely on the scolling function. Or if you set a variable to false to make sure the scoll function dont set the new values during the orientation complete. That could do the trick.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like setting the offsets in the 'orientationchange' event handler is working! Code looks like this:

$(window).on('orientationchange', function() {

    offset.scrollTop = $('#mapLeft').scrollTop();

    offset.scrollLeft = $('#mapLeft').scrollLeft();

    setTimeout(function() {

        $('#mapLeft').scrollTop(offset.scrollLeft);

        $('#mapLeft').scrollLeft(offset.scrollTop);

    }, 0);

});


This is obviously much better than using the scroll event, anyway. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @rumdrums you are welcome :) You can remove the settimeout if it's set to 0 :P